# How to check checkboxes with "KeyCode"? ( Windows Forms Application )

Tags: c#, .net, checkbox

i have to check checkboxes with "KeyCode". ( Hotkey ) I tried it but it has some errors... i hope you guys can help me :)

```
        private void NotYetHAX_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.KeyPreview = true;
        }

        private void HotKey_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.K)
            {
                checkbox1.Checked();
            }
            else
            {
                checkbox.Checked = false();
            }
        }
```

Comment: CheckBoxes don't really allow for user input. Standard Windows behaviour for them with the keyboard is to toggle the selection with the `SpaceBar`. Can you elaborate on what you want to achieve and what you expect the users to be doing, please?

Comment: Like when they press "K" checkbox will do something

Answer (score 0):

I'll list two things that you might have wanted to do here:

1. Based on your current code, it seems like you want `checkBox1` to be checked whenever the user presses 'K' and unchecked when the user presses anything else. In this case, all you need to do is to fix the syntax a little and the code will work:

   ```
   private void HotKey_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e) {
       if (e.KeyCode == Keys.K)
           checkBox1.Checked = true;
       else
           checkBox1.Checked = false;
   }
   ```

   Simplified:

   ```
   private void HotKey_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e) => this.checkBox1.Checked = (e.KeyCode == Keys.K);
   ```

   Add this to the event handler of every control that you want this to work from (i.e. you want to be able to check `checkBox1` whenever any of these controls are focused); this applies for the ones below as well.

   Careful about using the spacebar here to toggle it; unchecking with the spacebar doesn't work since the spacebar also acts as a "toggle" button. <s>If you want to, you can fix it by doing this (dirty method, if you want to make it look nicer you'll have to override the `CheckBox` class I think):</s>

   ```
   private void HotKey_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e) {
       if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
           checkBox1.Checked = !checkBox1.Checked
       else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.K)
           checkBox1.Checked = true;
       else
           checkBox1.Checked = false;
   }
   ```

   **EDIT: This code doesn't work if you hold down the space bar, so you'll have to override the** `CheckBox` **class if you want it to always function properly. However, another workaround is to simply disable the `CheckBox` if you don't need it to be clicked on.**
2. You want `checkBox1.Checked` to be toggled whenever 'K' is pressed

   In that case, this will do the trick:

   ```
   private void HotKey_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e) {
       if (e.KeyCode == Keys.K)
           checkBox1.Checked = !checkBox1.Checked;
   }
   ```